# How to create Horizontal Bar charts with clickable option in HTML5 in ASP .net MVC4 application?

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4, html5-canvas

I need a Horizontal bar chart in html5. The functionality should be as folows:

Bar chart should be developed in HTML5 with satisfying mvc4 concept. If i click a bar of chart, the bar should open in another page by displaying that as a graph. Its should be like subgroups within the group. All the bar charts data should dynamically get from the database. Suggest me some good ideas to implement this concept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pandiyan, you have to probably show a little more effort, and probably address to the rest of the community with a little more respect. This questions sounds like the rest of us are your employees and this is a requirement. :) Using "please" and "could you please suggest" would make this question less demmanding sounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say: "I never mind getting negative votes." … I'll label you as "doesn't play well with others"  :)

Anyway, there's a lot of excellent code that does the charting you need, but your key is how to use your MVC controller to inject that code into your view. Here's a great article on how to do that: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=822 .

You don’t want to use a chart plugin?

Ok then, here is html canvas code that will draw a barchart and detect when a user clicks a bar on the chart: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6vutD/

If you want more than a basic barchart, here’s an open-source chart code you can pull apart and use as you need: http://www.chartjs.org/

Here is code to the Fiddle above:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var barWidth=30;
    var barSpacing=15;
    var leftMargin=20;
    var bars=[]

    bars.push({height:150, color:"blue", x:null,y:null,right:null,bottom:null});
    bars.push({height:75, color:"green", x:null,y:null,right:null,bottom:null});
    bars.push({height:125, color:"gold", x:null,y:null,right:null,bottom:null});


    for(var i=0;i<bars.length;i++){
        bar=bars[i];
        bar.x=leftMargin+(barWidth+barSpacing)*i;
        bar.y=canvas.height-bar.height;
        bar.width=barWidth;
        bar.right=bar.x+barWidth;
        bar.bottom=canvas.height;
    }

    drawBarchart();

    function drawBarchart(){

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle="skyblue";
        ctx.fill();

        for(var i=0;i<bars.length;i++){
            bar=bars[i];
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(bar.x,bar.y,bar.width,bar.height);
            ctx.fillStyle=bar.color;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke()
        }
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      for(var i=0;i<bars.length;i++){
          var bar=bars[i];
          if(mouseX>=bar.x 
                && mouseX<=bar.right
                && mouseY>=bar.y
                && mouseY<=bar.bottom){
              alert("Clicked on ["+bar.color.toUpperCase()+"] so open another chart!");
          }
      }
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks quite useful. No plugins needed.

http://g.raphaeljs.com/

There are a lot of other libraries out there for creating html graphs. Just use Google & look for one that meets your requirements.